# NTFS disk mounted as fuseblk in ubuntu 12.10 is very slow and a lot of errors when rsync. Is that not a rare thing?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ntfs, fuse

I am having problems with a NTFS disk mounted as a fuseblk in my ubuntu 12.10 through external usb3.

When I did a 1.1TB backup with rsync the speed was 1-2MB/s (wiht a ext4 disk speed was 70 MB/s before and after trying the NTFS disk). Also after one hour errors started to appear:

- rsync: write failed on "xxx": No such file or directory
- recv_files: "yyy" is a directory  #but this file is a FILE not a dir ??!!
- ....

As this is the first time I have mounted the NTFS in linux for heavy usage (the data would be used in windows afterwards), I would like to know if this kind of thinks are common o was only that something became unstable in my system and a simply restart would probably have solved it.

This leads me to the these questions:

- Can I trust fuse for manage NTFS disks?
- Or is a problem of the NTFS tools in linux not yet totally stables for writing?
- Do people is still suffering from low performance with fuse-NTFS vs ext4 (in the past I have read about people complaining about this)?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that it is still useful to answer after 6 years, but you cannot expect to have good results with `fuse`. As it stands for *Filesystem in Userspace* it cannot have comparable performances as kernel drivers.

You must probably have to re-format your drive, so that is uses NTFS of ext4.

Comment: Why would reformatting be necessary when `ntfs-3g` exists?  Generally speaking, it's best to let old questions stay dead, unless an answer would apply to the issue today.

Comment: Actually I've hit the same problem today, with an external USB disk showing "Microsoft basic data" as partition type, and mount using fuseblk. Working, but performances are not good at all compared to kernel drivers like ntfs-3g. In this case, re-partitioning / formating of the disk is - IMHO - the solution.

Comment: Why not install `ntfs-3g` then?  You appear to make the point I'm making _("...but performance [is] not good at all compared to kernel drivers like `ntfs-3g`...")_, but then say formatting is the solution... Your comment is contradictory.

Comment: I agree, I was not clear :-) `ntfs-3g` is great.